# Display images from Google Drive using NetworkImage

Tags: flutter

I am trying to load some images into a gridview. Each GridTile contains a container with a decoration that uses a NetworkImage. All the images I'm using are stored in google drive and the problem is that for some reason, flutter does not like Google Drive urls. I've tried the following urls:

- https://docs.google.com/uc?id={fileId}
- https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileId}
- https://drive.google.com/a/{domain}.com/uc?authuser=0&id=fileId}&export=download
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileId}/view

None of the above is working. It throws the following error:

> The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
>   Exception: Could not instantiate image codec.

What I've noticed is that all of those urls end up redirecting to another link, probably where the image is cached. Is that the reason why is not working? If that is so, how can I force it to follow redirects?

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
String imgUrl = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/$fileId/view";
GridTile(
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        openDriveImage(fileId);
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black38,
          ),
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          image: DecorationImage(
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            image: NetworkImage(imgUrl),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it results that all of the options mentioned in the question work. Nothing has to be changed. The problem is that the images are private hence it was failing to fetch them. In order to get fetch the images, I had to implement [Google Sign In](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in#-readme-tab-).

After the user is signed in, I simply grab the access token and put it in the headers of the NetworkImage class like this:

```
NetworkImage(imgUrl, headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer ${accessToken}"})
```

After that, I was able to fetch the images with any of the url's.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how you got a viable accessToken? The implementation I'm using doesn't work

Comment: @BernardinDezius I guess your question is geared towards how getting a token via google sign in. I suggest you to look for other questions or ask your own.

Comment: Thx, I was able to confirm using Postman that my implementation was right. It' the url giving me trouble. Have you had any luck using this method for getting thumbnail images?

Answer (score 26):

Here are the steps:

1. Right click the image and click `Share` as shown below;[image]
2. In the dialog that appears, make sure the option selected from the dropdown is
   `Anyone with the link can view` as shown below:
   [image]
3. After, click `Copy link` and then paste it somewhere
4. It should be something like this `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VdjEgb0aZl9IZa2jOzGU5_SNbmlmeiCj/view?usp=sharing` which is in the format

   > https://drive.google.com/file/d/**<FILE_ID>**/view?usp=sharing
5. Copy the **<FILE_ID>** which in my case is `1VdjEgb0aZl9IZa2jOzGU5_SNbmlmeiCj`
6. Append it to this link below in the following format:

   > https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=**<FILE_ID>**
7. In my case for example, the final link is:

   > https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1VdjEgb0aZl9IZa2jOzGU5_SNbmlmeiCj
8. Finally get that link and paste in a `NetworkImage()` or `Image.network()` widget and your done

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answers, I make this snippet code to automate editing google drive sharing a link:

```
 String originalLink = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PpUCg8U0YkedIPYmm2NtLXt00JsdBJt2';
String fileId =
    originalLink.substring(originalLink.indexOf('/d/') + 3, originalLink.indexOf('/view'));

String newLink = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=$fileId';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the links like i did below:

Link given by Google Drive when link sharing is made on: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PpUCg8U0YkedIPYmm2NtLXt00JsdBJt2

Now replace the **open?** from the Url with the **uc?export=download&**

So the Url that will work with NetworkImage() widget is: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1PpUCg8U0YkedIPYmm2NtLXt00JsdBJt2

Comment: If my solution solved your problem then you should mark it as accepted answer, it will be helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem was something else. I really appreciate your help efforts!

Comment: Welcome, but i thought images link are shared in public mode. So i shared the above solution.

Comment: hey how can i do with thumbnail ?
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=<imageId>
this is not working.

Comment: @Kishan
**For Image files shared publicly**


To download thumbnail for images you should do the following:
This is the link to the image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PpUCg8U0YkedIPYmm2NtLXt00JsdBJt2

To get a thumbnail of that image: https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1PpUCg8U0YkedIPYmm2NtLXt00JsdBJt2